# How to view the output of kable and kableExtra correctly in an R notebook?

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook, kable, kableextra

I'm having a lot of trouble rendering `kable` and `kableExtra` output correctly using R Notebooks, both inline and in the HTML Preview.

I've changed the print handling in the YAML header to `kable` (not sure this is necessary?):

```
---
title: "MIPS Sample Overlap with ASC"
output:
  html_notebook:
    theme: lumen
    df_print: kable
  html_document:
    df_print: kable
  pdf_document: default
---
```

When I run the command inside the notebook, the output appears inline, however there are two problems:

1. It usually has a very large empty white space at the bottom.
2. It always replaces my whole notebook preview in the RStuduio Viewer with a copy of just the `kable_styling()` output.

[image]

When I reload the notebook preview, the table is now rendered in its proper context, but **without the lines** seen in the inline output. This happens with `kable` alone as well.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!